# Why outputText wrapped in div is not rendered?

Tags: jsf-2

Do you have any idea why the following outputText component is not rendered when wrapped inside a div?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Welcome</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <div>
            <h:outputText>This line will not be rendered</h:outputText>
        </div>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

For example, the HTML page is rendered like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
    <title>Welcome</title></head><body>
    <div>
    </div></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<h:outputText value="This line will be rendered"/>
```

See http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_outputText.html

Comment: Yeah, you basically don't have a choice. You *have* to put the text in the `value` attribute.